# PHP script not running in Command Prompt Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, windows, twitter, service

I am currently working on a Twitter project to collect all the tweets from Twitter so i decided to use Streaming API. I referred from this [link](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/)  and followed the steps. I would also like to use [AlwaysUp Windows Service](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunPHPScriptAsAService.html) instead of *nix server to run `get_tweets.php` and `parse_tweets.php` continuously in the background.

However, when I tried to run `get_tweets.php` in the command prompt by typing:

```
C:\php\php.exe C:\www\140dev\db\get_tweets.php
```

the command prompt did not show any results or errors. When I run parse_tweets.php in command line, it has no results and errors too, but it states

```
Administrator: Command Prompt - C:\php\php.exe C:\www\140dev\db\parse_tweets.php
```

on the title bar of the command prompt. (I believe this is running parse_tweets.php successfully because the script can be run continuously in AlwaysUp Service too, which is what I want.)

On the other hand, get_tweets.php did not display the path of the script on the title bar. I tried to run it in AlwaysUp Service but it stopped automatically after a few seconds. I checked the event log and it only states that the get_tweets application entered in a stop state. Wondering if any kind souls can enlighten me or any reference for me to guide? Thank you in advance.

Note: I use Apache, PHP, MySQL, and Localhost server

Answer (score 0):

You should run the PHP as follow:

```
C:\php\php.exe -f "C:\www\140dev\db\parse_tweets.php"
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Available command line options: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt reply. However, there is still no result or errors in the Command Prompt after typing the above line.

Comment: try putting an `echo` line on line 1 and `exit();` on line 2. Re-run the line to isolate issues.

Comment: Do you mean to type
    echo "Hello"
    exit();
in the command prompt?

Comment: I typed echo "Hello"; exit(); right in get_tweets.php and ran the command line. There is output of Hello in the Command Prompt but the title bar still didnt show the path of the script.

Comment: Yes, as the execution has been complete. Proven that your original PHP script contains error / logic issues / connection issues. Use `var_dump()` , `var_export()` or `print_r()` to investigate the real issue.